# Why does this ElasticSearch scan and scroll returns IndexMissingException

Tags: elasticsearch

I run the following:

```
curl -XGET 'http://my_address/my_index/_search?scroll=1m&size=10&search_type=scan' -d '{'query':{'match_all':{}}}'
```

It returns a scroll id (very long), and I then use in the first scroll request:

```
curl -XGET 'http://my_address/my_index/_search/scroll?scroll=1m' -d '<scroll_id>'
```

It returns an error: {"error":"IndexMissingException[[my_index] missing]","status":404}

I do not know why having this error. I follow the guideline in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html step by step.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Because your second request (i.e. using the `scroll_id`) should not take any index and read like this instead:

```
curl -XGET 'http://my_address/_search/scroll?scroll=1m' -d '<scroll_id>'
```